# SELECT all records with text in a phone field

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to write a MySQL query that will select all records where the telephone field has non numeric characters other than a dash or (space)x. All other spaces included.

I want to select all the phone numbers that are formatted:
000 000 0000, (000) 000-0000, 1-800-OurPhoneNumber, 000.000.0000, 000000000 ext 0

Basically I want anything that is not formatted: 000-000-0000 or 000-000-0000 x0000

I know there has to be a REGEXP that can select this, but I can't for the life of me seem to wrap my head around REGEXP's

So far I have `SELECT * FROM customer WHERE telephone NOT REGEXP '[0-9]+'` but that won't even return customers with outlandish numbers like 1-800-HIDEYOKIDSHIDEYOWIFE

Comment: You'd probably have better luck dropping the `NOT` and putting the negative into the regexp itself - for example, `[^0-9]` matches any character NOT a digit from 0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, use `^` and `$`

I always find it useful to get as specific as possible with a regex.

`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE telephone NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\sx[0-9]+$';`

Whether you go for a loose or tight regex depends on what data you are trying to get and why.

Comment: This worked almost perfect. Still missed ones like 000-000-0000h / 000--000-0000c

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the regexp to the beginning and end with `^` and `$`.

```
WHERE telephone NOT REGEXP '^[-0-9]+$'
```

Or you can use a complemented character set:

```
WHERE telephone REGEXP '[^-0-9]'
```

Putting `^` at the beginning of a character set makes it match any character not in the set.

Allowing for the optional extension makes it a little more complicated:

```
WHERE telephone NOT REGEXP '^[-0-9]+( x[0-9]+)?$'
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation the last one is almost exactly what I am looking for. How would I include numbers that do not include the -? For example: 0000000000